# Should you declare enums inside or outside a class?

Tags: c++, coding-style, enums, namespaces

Should you declare enums inside or outside a class if the said enums are only used in the class member functions?

```
namespace nspace
{

// need to append OC, as this pollutes the current namespace
enum OUTSIDE_CLASS {OC_POINTS, OC_LINES, OC_LINE_LOOP, :::};
enum OTHER_ENUM {OE_POINTS};
class VertexBuffer
{
public:
    enum INSIDE_CLASS {POINTS, LINES, LINE_LOOP, :::};
    void foo(OUTSIDE_CLASS e);
    void bar(INSIDE_CLASS e);
}
};

// usage
nspace::VertexBuffer v;
v.foo(nspae::VB_POINTS);
v.bar(nspace::VertexBuffer::POINTS); // more pedantic
```

Comment: As with all [coding-style] questions, the answer is "it depends."

Comment: Someone might have a bit more insight on this than me, but my strategy has always been to not expose something until it needs to be exposed.  (In other words, if it's just used internally, then keep it internal.)

Comment: As usual with coding style questions, there's no definite answer. Polluting the global scope is usually not a good idea due to the risk of conflicting declarations, but if you're keeping within your "own" namespace, it's strictly a matter of preference.

Comment: I declare enums (or whatever for that matter) inside class in private section, only if it is *internally* needed by the class itself. In all other cases, I prefer to define it outside, especially in C++11, because if you declare this inside class, you wouldn't be able to use it in lambda.

Comment: You might be able to refactor and [replace the enum with a class hierarchy](http://martinfowler.com/refactoring/catalog/replaceTypeCodeWithSubclasses.html), for example the state or strategy patterns.

Comment: +1 to counter the close-voter kids.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The real goal is to avoid polluting the scope (either global or namespace) and help grouping related values together (works pretty goods with autocompletion in IDE).

With C++11, you can declare strongly typed enums using:

```
enum class MyEnum {
  Value0,
  Value1
};
```

which are necessarily invoked as `MyEnum::Value0` (and not `Value0`).

In C++03, you can more or less emulate this with:

```
struct MyEnum {
  enum Type {
    Value0,
    Value1
  };
};
```

But then the type of the enum is `MyEnum::Type` which is subtly different.

The lazy option is to just dump it in a class, but I still favor nesting a scoped enum, even within a class, just to make it clear that those values are not *loose* but instead are *inter-related*.

Comment: -1 "This avoid polluting the global scope." No it does not, but if that declaration has to be in the global scope (which it seldom has to), then the pollution is reduced to a single name (the type name) instead of multiple names (the enum values).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Right, leftover from my thought train, the real intent was expressed in the introduction *avoid polluting the scope (either global or namespace)*. I would recommend always using namespaces... expect that script like programs (in C++, yes!) seldom require it.

Answer (score 7):

If only your class members use the `enum` it is preferable to declare the `enum` inside the class.
This prevents the namespace/global space from pollution due to unneeded symbol names & also
It is more intutive for users of the class, it helps the user to know that the `enum` will only be used by the class.

The general rule you should follow is:
**Do not add any symbol in a scope(global/namespace) which will not be accessed(& hence not needed) in that scope.**

Comment: -1 the global namespace is not the only alternative to in-class declaration.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: The answer does not say global namespace is an alternative to in class declaration it just says why it is not a good idea in this case. I am a bit confused as to what you are downvoting for here.

Comment: "This prevents the global space from pollution" would not make sense without the assumption that the global namespace is the only alternative.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Ah, okay. Modified to reflect the subtle point You made.

Comment: However, OP enum declaration is public, hence it is accesible by `nspace::VertexBuffer::POINTS`. You should add a note to your answer about making it private/protected.

Answer (score 0):

As Matthieu M. mentioned, in C++11 use [Strongly typed enumerations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Strongly_typed_enumerations).

A good way to emulate them in C++03 is to wrap enums in namespaces. It is better than wrapping  in a `struct` because that namespace may have functions that can be found using argument-dependent name lookup. E.g.:

```
namespace MyEnum {
  enum Type {
    Value0,
    Value1
  };

  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Type);
  std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Type&);
}

MyEnum::Type value;
std::cout << value; // uses the overload from MyEnum
std::cin >> value; // uses the overload from MyEnum
```

Comment: -1 "it is better because" should be "I prefer because". For example, I prefer wrapping in structs because structs can be typedef'ed inside classes (you can not have "using namespace" inside a class). The way I've written that now is OK, but if I make a claim that my preference is "better" then someone else's preference, then it it would be a meaningless or just incorrect claim.

Comment: As Alf said, I prefer using structs for the `typedef` ability. Placing the functions in the namespace in which the struct containing the enum resides is sufficient for ADL to kick in.

Comment: @Alf: `typedef` and `using namespace` do different things, so it's not clear why you compared them, you may like to elaborate. I wrote "better" and explained how.

Comment: -1 wrapping enums in a `namespace` is not better because namespaces are open for extension. I.e. some unrelated piece of code may do `namespace MyEnum { int Value0; }` and thus trigger a compile error.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe You can extend any namespace like that, your argument is not specific to an enum in a namespace.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Indeed, and thus I'm convinced it's not "better" to put enums into a namespace as opposed to using a `struct`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Strive to minimize exposure of implementation details. E.g. enclose things in namespaces and/or classes and/or separately compiled implementation files. And as that hopefully makes very clear, the global namespace and in-class are absolutely not the only options. I.e., declaring something in-class is not the only way to minimize exposure (what are some other ways then? --- oh, well, remember the third sentence of this answer).