# Why put an enum in a struct and then use a typedef name?

Tags: c++, enums, c++03

I've found the following pattern used fairly commonly in our company's code.

```
struct Foo
{
    enum FType
    {
        TypeA,
        TypeB,
        Type_MAX
    };
};
typedef Foo::FType FooType;
[...]
FooType m_type;
```

My question is, what is the benefit of this? (Or, what problem does this avoid?) To be clear, I am wondering why they didn't just...

```
enum FooType
{
    TypeA,
    TypeB,
    Type_MAX
};
[...]
FooType m_type;
```

I can't ask the original programmer because they have been re-assigned, and it turns out that the designated subject matter expert in our company is, in fact, me.

If it helps, this code has been compiled at various times using many versions of MSVC, gcc, and clang for different target platforms... all pre C++11.

Can anyone see why this was done?
Apologies in advance, if the answer turns out to be something trivial.

Edited to add: This is used **inside** classes. (When an enum is global, our style guide requires entries to begin with a common prefix, in order to distinguish them from other symbols.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should you declare enums inside or outside a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630744/should-you-declare-enums-inside-or-outside-a-class)

Comment: _"it turns out that the designated subject matter expert in our company is, in fact, me"_ hehe :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I know that feeling. Someone tells that you are only one who may know and there is that urge to curl up after you had listened to the question. Or attack table with head and regret that you don't have something sharp on hand.

Comment: I always recite simple concept "class'  name is also a namespace". It solves most of problems with understanding.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie: See also: "The Expert - a sketch"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit oh, I know that one.. there are dozen of parodies on that, including MMOs and various fic crossovers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The perceived problem with plain old enums is that the enumerators become names in the scope where the enum is defined. As a result, you could say, for example,

```
FooType m_type;
m_type = TypeA;
```

If you had also defined a class names `TypeA` you'd have a conflict. Putting the enum inside a class means you have to use a scope qualifier to get at the name, which would remove the conflict. It also means you'd have to write

```
FooType m_type;
m_type = FooType::TypeA;
```

because the previous version wouldn't be valid.

A newer solution to this problem is scoped enums:

```
enum class FooType {
    TypeA,
    TypeB,
    Type_MAX
};
```

Now you can say

```
FooType m_type;
m_type = FooType::TypeA;
```

but not

```
m_type = TypeA;
```

One difference here, as @Jarod42 points out, is that an enumerator defined by a plain enum can be implicitly converted to `int`, while an enumerator from a scoped enum is not. So with the definition inside a class,

```
int i = FooType::TypeA;
```

is valid, and `i` gets the value 0. With a scoped enum it is not valid.

In both cases, a cast makes the conversion okay:

```
int i = static_cast<int>(FooType::TypeA);
```

Comment: Note that `enum class` is not equivalent to `enum` in class: no implicit conversion with `int`.

Comment: @Jarod42 -- added. Thanks.

Comment: until c++11 compilers didn't recognize that enum is part of class' scope. Some could issue warning about using class' name.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie -- are you saying that the C++ language definition required enumerators defined in an enum that is, in turn defined inside a class, be injected into global scope? I don't think that was ever the rule; do you have authority for that? Or are you talking about some particular compiler?

Comment: Thanks for this answer (and to those who wrote equivalent/similar answers below!)
In retrospect this seems very obvious. Having said that.... the technique is usually used when the 'enum' is inside a class, in which case polluting the scope shouldn't be a problem. I think I'm going to chalk this up to a house style guide that is too eager to make prescriptions.
Thanks again, everyone.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely this was done to prevent polluting the global scope with the `enum` members.  When you have

```
enum FooType
{
    TypeA,
    TypeB,
    Type_MAX
};
```

`TypeA`, `TypeB` and `Type_MAX` become names in the global scope.  This could cause conflicts with other `enum`s or just other names already in use.  By placing the `enum` in a `struct` you limit the names to being the the scope of the struct.  Another way this is accomplished is using a `namespace`.

C++11 offers [`enum class`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335861/why-is-enum-class-preferred-over-plain-enum) that keeps the `enum` members scoped to the `enum` itself so this is no longer needed if you can deal with the more strict controls `enum class` imposes.

Comment: Using a `namespace` is not ideal, since namespaces can be expanded anywhere else and names are often used unqualified.

Answer (score 1):

You should always put `enum`'s inside a `struct` (or a `class`) in pre-C++11. The reason for it is that it prevents pollution of the global `namespace` and it forces qualified names when using the members of the struct. i.e `Foo::TypeA`. Why? because otherwise someone else might decide to create a constant or another `enum` member named `TypeA` somewhere else in the code and there would be a name conflict.

The `typedef` is probably just for the convenience of not typing the fully qualified `enum` type name every time.

This only apply to pre C++11. C++11 has `enum class` which declares a scoped enum. You mentioned that this code was written before that.

Answer (score 1):

There probably wasn't `enum class` in C++ when this code was written, so that was the only solution to avoid outer namespace pollution.

Struct is used here more like a namespace. Still the author probably wanted name of enum itself to be in outer namespace, which is done by `typedef`.

Answer (score 1):

In older C++ versions the enum names are added to the surrounding namespace.

In your second example I can do:

```
m_type = TypeA;
```

In the original example you need to do:

```
m_type = FooType::TypeA;
```

If TypeA is something fairly common in your application, I can see why you wouldn't want to pollute the namespace around it.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, what is the benefit of this? (Or, what problem does this avoid?)

It limits the individual enumeration identifiers into the namespace of the class:

```
int TypeA;

struct Foo
{
    enum FType
    {
        TypeA, // OK, Foo::TypeA does not conflict with ::TypeA
        TypeB,
        Type_MAX,
    };
};

enum FooType
{
    TypeA, // not OK, conflicts with the existing ::TypeA declaration
    TypeB,
    Type_MAX,
};
```

The programmer could have used a namespace instead, which might have been clearer.